# Деинициализация static класса

Tags: c#, .net

Как "обнулить" статический класс не дописывая метод `Reset` к `Foo`?

Пусть есть класс `Foo`

```
static class Foo
{
    public static int F;

    static Foo()
    {
        F = 42;
    }
}
```

Используем его:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo.F = 20;
    ...

//Тут "обнуление":

// clear Foo
//И дальше если используем Foo.F то получаем значение 42:

    Console.WriteLine(Foo.F); // expected 42;
}
```

Comment: Вам не должно такого хотеться. Расскажите, какая ваша настоящая проблема. (тм)

Comment: @VladD, я думаю я раскрыл всю суть вопрос..

Comment: Вы описали синтаксис, но не семантику. То есть, _как_ оно должно себя вести, но не _почему_ вам нужно такое странное поведение.

Comment: @VladD, да, извиняюсь, за формулирование вопроса перед всеми, по сути мой вопрос свелся к "как вызвать конструктор".. Удалить вопрос?

Comment: Не стоит удалять — вопрос сам по себе имеет смысл.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Неправильный способ

Вы можете воспользоваться отражениями, чтобы повторно вызвать статический конструктор:

```
typeof(Foo).TypeInitializer.Invoke(null, null);
```

## Костыльный способ

Не нарушайте закон CLR, что статический конструтор вызывается только один раз. Напишите нормальный статический метод `Reset`. В статическом конструкторе можно вызвать его, чтобы не дублировать код.

## Нормальный способ

Постарайтесь воздержаться от глобального состояния, на которое может повлиять абсолютно любой класс и от которого также может зависеть любой класс. Глобальные переменные — зло.

Comment: Да, опечатка, спасибо

Comment: Я не имею возможности что-то дописать в статический класс (без IL-инъекции)..

Comment: @AntonKomyshan Если класс вам не принадлежит, то с этого и надо было начинать. Тогда остаётся только хак с отражениями, собственно.

Comment: воспользовался не правильным способом :)

Answer (score 4):

Статические конструкторы в .NET не обязательно вызываются не больше одного раза. Если быть точным - то они вызываются не больше одного раза в пределах каждого App Domain.

Поэтому самый простой способ "деинициализировать" класс - перенести всю работу с ним в отдельный App Domain. А по окончанию использования - просто выгрузить, вместе с App Domain. Вот минимальный пример:

```
static class Foo
{
    public static int F;

    static Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Initializing, F = " + F);
        F = 42;
        Console.WriteLine("Initialized, F = " + F);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CreateDomain("domain1").DoCallBack(() => Console.WriteLine("F is " + Foo.F));
        AppDomain.CreateDomain("domain2").DoCallBack(() => Console.WriteLine("F is " + Foo.F));
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Пробовал. Слишком "дорого" загружать потом снова домен.

Comment: @AntonKomyshan тогда опишите в вопросе реальную задачу, которую вы хотите решить.